# Finding World Space Coordinates of a Unity UI Element

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

So according to the Unity documentation [RectTransform.anchoredPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) will return the screen coordinates of a UI element if the anchors are touching at the pivot point of the RectTransform.  However, if they are separated (in my case positioned at the corners of the rect) they will give you the position of the anchors relative to the pivot point.  This is wonderful unless you want to keep appropriate dimensions of a UI object through multiple resolutions and position a different object based on that position at the same time.

Let's break this down.  I have object1 and object2.  object1 is positioned at (322.5, -600) and when the anchor points meet at the center (pivot) of the object anchoredPosition returns just that and object2 is positioned just fine.  On the other hand once I have placed the anchors at the 4 corners of object1 anchoredPosition returns (45.6, -21).  Thats just no good. I've even tried using `Transform.position` and then `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()`, but that does just about as much to getting me to my goal.

I was hoping that you might be able to help me find a way to get the actual screen coordinates of this object. If anyone has any insight into this subject it would be greatly appreciated.

**Notes:** I've already attempted to use RectTranfrom.rect.center and it returned (0, 0)

I've also looked into [RectTransformUtility](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.html) and those helper functions have done all of squat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

anchoredPosition returns "The position of the pivot of this RectTransform relative to the anchor reference point."  It has nothing to do with screen coordinates or world space.

If you're looking for the screen coordinates of a UI element in Unity, you can either use `rectTransform.TransformPoint` or `rectTransform.GetWorldCorners` to get any of the `Vector3`s you'd need in world space.  Which ever you decide to go with, you can then pass them into `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()`

Comment: Is there any reason using `rectTransform.TransformPoint` would work better than `transform.position`?

Comment: @user1311199  I recommended TransformPoint because its return position is affected by scale and you mentioned you're working with multiple resolutions so I'm assuming there's some scaling going on.  transform.position will still work if you're not worried about this.  As long as you can get the actual world position, Camera.WorldToScreenPoint() works;  I've experienced no bugs with it in the most recent release of Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a glimpse on how finding world space coordinates of UI elements works if your stuck and need to roll your own transformations from view-space to world-space.

This may be beneficial if say you need something more than rectTransform.TransformPoint or want to know how this works.

Ok, so you want to do a transformation from normalised UI coordinates in the range [-1, 1], and de-project them back into world space coordinates.

To do this you could use something like Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint or Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint, or even rectTransform.position if your a lacker.

This is how to do it with just the camera's projection matrix.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the world position of an anchor/normalised device coordinate in the range [-1, 1]
/// </summary>
private Vector3 GetAnchor(Vector2 ndcSpace)
{
    Vector3 worldPosition;

    Vector4 viewSpace = new Vector4(ndcSpace.x, ndcSpace.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Transform to projection coordinate.
    Vector4 projectionToWorld = (_mainCamera.projectionMatrix.inverse * viewSpace);

    // Perspective divide.
    projectionToWorld /= projectionToWorld.w;

    // Z-component is backwards in Unity.
    projectionToWorld.z = -projectionToWorld.z;

    // Transform from camera space to world space.
    worldPosition = _mainCamera.transform.position + _mainCamera.transform.TransformVector(projectionToWorld);

    return worldPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ScreenToWorldPoint convert canvas position to world position :

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(transform.position)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that you can multiply your coordinate by the 2 times the camera size and divide it to screen height.

I have a panel placed at (0, 1080) on a fullHD screen (1920 x 1080), camera size is 7. So the Y coordinate in world space will be `1080 * 7 * 2 / 1080 = 14 -> (0, 14).`